# Is it possible to host a hidden service with a v2 onion address using Tor 0.4.1.5, and if so how?

Tags: onion-services

Is it possible to host a hidden service with a v2 onion address using Tor 0.4.1.5, and if so how?

I have to use a tor client that has not yet been updated to use v3 onion addresses. I have tried to host my hidden service to use both v2 and v3 by having the following lines in my torrc, but both addresses end up being v3.

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hsv3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
HiddenServiceVersion 2
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hsv2
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onion service options apply to the earlier/previous `HiddenServiceDir` option, so I would expect your `hsv3` address to be v2, and your `hsv2` to be v3.

You should move the `HiddenServiceVersion 2` line after your `HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hsv2` line:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hsv3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hsv2
HiddenServiceVersion 2
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Note that v2 onion addresses are deprecated and will be removed from the network in the near future.

Comment: Thank you Steve, this solves the problem completely. I don't have enough points yet to upvote, but will as soon as I can.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!